# Binding RichTextBox inside of dataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, richtextbox, rtf

So I have this WPF app to pull data from database and display in dataGrid:
[image: dataGrid]

This app store rtf format code in **[Content]**. I want it to convert every listing under **[Content]** and show it in the richtextbox inside of my dataGrid.

My XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ColumnWidth="*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="512" Width="774" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Ttile" Width="100" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Content" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb">
                            <FlowDocument Name="rtbFlowDoc" PageWidth="{Binding ElementName=rtb, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </FlowDocument>
                        </RichTextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Image">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Files}" Width="300" Height="300" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My C# for converting rtf to content(how do you auto convert each datarow btw?):

```
string rtfText = text;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtfText);
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    System.Windows.Documents.TextRange tr = new System.Windows.Documents.TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
    tr.Load(ms, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Also I think you should get your dog looked at.

Comment: You would use an [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the value using your custom code. There's plenty of examples online if you need assistance with it.